# Google Analytics Autotrack not displaying SPA page path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to display the page views in Google Analytics using Autotrack for a SPA (Single Page Application). I was able to get the page path after # prefix before, but i'm not getting them now.

Code:

```
<script>
        window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
        window.ga_debug = {trace: true};
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');

        // Replace the following lines with the plugins you want to use.
        ga('require', 'urlChangeTracker', {
        shouldTrackUrlChange: function(newPath, oldPath) {
            // Strips the query string from the path values.
            newPath = newPath.split('?')[0];
            oldPath = oldPath.split('?')[0];

            return newPath != oldPath;
          }
        });
        if (window.performance) {
            var timeSincePageLoad = Math.round(performance.now());
            ga('send', 'timing', 'JS Dependencies', 'load', timeSincePageLoad);
        }
        ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        <script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
        <script async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autotrack/0.6.4/autotrack.js"></script>
```

Can  anyone tell me what's the problem?

Comment: same problem here, I opened an issue here: https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/issues/146

Comment: my issue was closed because URL Fragments are not supported. Please note that if you change only #... parts, URL change will not be detected